# Refund to credit card account with 0 balance

Tags: credit-card, refund

I am due a refund from a company and they are sending back the money to my credit card (the card I used for the original purchase).

However my credit card balance is  paid off, so how will this refund be applied ?

Can my credit card go into positive credit ?

The CC is with Barclaycard in the UK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the amount isn’t too large, they will likely leave the refund in your account as a positive balance, which you would spend the next time you make a purchase. If you aren’t planning on using your card anytime soon, you can just call Barclaycard and ask them to send you a check.

Comment: That's exactly correct.  But note - actually this was a recent question - in most jurisdictions now you can NOT just make a PAYMENT that puts you in credit (due to money laundering BS).

Comment: When COVID hit, we cancelled a trip, and requested a refund from the airline. The $3000 credit sat on the account, a card used for gas/restaurant/travel. After 3 months, the positive balance, about $2000, was sent to us in a check. @Fattie - I routinely pay more than owed at month end on my major card, as they report the balance by calendar, not by statement balance. Half the time, pending transactions will zero it out, other times, the 1th of the month, I have a credit, gone within a few days with new purchases. I don't think this is a law in the US.

Comment: American express has stopped me from overpaying such that I'd have a statement credit, using the online portal, I'm not sure what would happen if I sent a check.

Comment: @quid - They'd almost certainly let it work with a check.  They don't _want_ to let you overpay, and blocking you from doing so on the website also helps in case someone forgets the decimal point or adds a digit.  But if they do get excess money, they need to return it to you in some form, and a statement credit is easiest.

Comment: I tried simply to see what would happen, I have zero clue why anyone would want to lend their credit card bank money. With the exception of the bank accidently paying the borrowing interest rate on the balance I have no idea why anyone would want to overpay to the extent that the account would be negative in your favor and I know the Amex payment tool stops it from happening.

Comment: Thanks, as for calling Barclay card it takes hours just to get through, hence me asking the question on here :)

Comment: @quid One reason could be to ease automated payments, another one could be to raise the CC limit for a potential next payment.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that you can go into a positive balance on Visa credit cards in the UK as I sat on one for almost a decade until very recently. A refund similar to what you are describing is exactly how this happened to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would receive the refund and it would get a positive card balance. Depending on the policy of your card provider, it may stay positive till you spend more and bring it down to zero or negative, or your card provider may cut you a check automatically at the end of the billing cycle.

I have seen both happen in the US (BofA won't automatically cut a check but CapitalOne would) but I am not aware if there is any additional regulation in the UK that forces banks to do it one way or another. If I recall, I was able to keep a positive balance with HSBC but it is more than a decade ago.

Comment: Fascinating info in your last paragraph, good one...